# Horizontal scrollbar for visjs timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Is it possible to bind a horizontal scrollbar to timeline? I need to implement a horizontal scrollbar for visjs timeline. When the time line is dragged the scrollbar should update itself and when i scroll the time line should move smoothly.

Maybe i can use the moveRight and MoveLeft to simulate this behaviour?
 http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/interaction/navigationMenu.html

Comment: do you know hot show horizontal scroll ?

Comment: There's a `horizontalScroll` property that can be enabled, but you have to turn off `zoomable` according to the docs.  However, I can't seem to get this to work in my timeline

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to directly add a horizontal scrollbar.
Best you can do is to add a sibling (element A) with same width of your vis.js timeline element, below it, which contains a 0px tall (height) child element (element B) that has a dynamic width that is inversely proportional to the zoom-out level, and bind an event listener to its parent (element A) scroll event, so that when the scroll event happens, vis.js "moves" to another location.
Likewise you have to bind an event listener when the zoom event happens in vis.js so this new visible timerange can be used to calculate how big shall be element B and match its orizontal position so the scrollbar-thumb size is always centered on the same point (if possible).