# What is the "horizontalScroll" option in Vis.js supposed to do?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

Vis.js has a great, customiziable timeline. It's easy to use but the docs and some of the naming of the variables and options are a bit ... opaque. In particular I am looking at the `horizontalScroll` option.

Here is an [example](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/horizontalScroll.html).  It is completely unclear to me what the  `horizontalScroll` option is supposed to do. There is no horizontal scrollbar there (in Chrome on OSX). In my test project, if I set it to true or to false it makes no difference: the timeline can always be dragged horizontally and no scrollbar appears when it is set to true.

I'm asking because I need a horizontal scrollbar in a timeline which has defined min and max dates. This earlier question from last year didn't get any answers ([Horizontal scrollbar for visjs timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740571/horizontal-scrollbar-for-visjs-timeline)). Maybe someone knows a bit more now, or can tell me what I should be seeing with the `horizontalScroll` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this line of the vis.js source](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/bc2bc581aaa16905f2ee15b26d3915648c34cc54/lib/timeline/Range.js#L583).

If `horizontalScroll` is true, using the mouse wheel will scroll left and right on your timeline.

Comment: Ah – thanks. Again, a poorly named var in `vis.js.` What confused me is that there actually *is* a vertical scroll bar which comes up, so I figured this was its horizontal equivalent.

Comment: Actually horizontalScroll = true, does not work as described by Matt.... if you have verticalScroll and horizontalScroll only vertical scroll is allowed over all gantt, any help?